# Send form to cgi with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, cgi

I want to send a form and control what happens after with jQuery. **I cannot use php**. My server have cgi to process the data. How to send the form to the cgi using jQuery?. I don't know how to do it but I tried things like this:

```
$(function(){

   var name = $("input:text").val("name"); ;

   $(":submit").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      load("http://cgi.myDomain.com/FormMail.pl", ( name ));
   });

})
```

- The html:

  ```
  <Form id="formulari" method="POST" action="http://cgi.aDomain/FormMail.pl">
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="anE-mail">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form send">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.theSamePage.html">  
  </p>

  <form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
  </form>

  </div>

  <div class="answer">Thank you</div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX, with it you can submit your form using POST or GET method and you receive an answer from your server. Also, it allows you to make things happen without reload your page.

here is a cool tuturial

[Ajax tuturial](http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery)

**EDIT**

try this, please note that I'm just using this piece of html, no form, just the input elements

**html**

```
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="name"/>
    <input class="send" type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
    $('.send').on('click', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://cgi.aDomain.com/FormMail.pl",
            data: {name: $("#name").val()},
            error: function(result) {
                var data_received = $(result).find("h1");
                alert(data_received );
            },
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I cannot use php. Is there a way to send the form to cgi?

Comment: Thank you Pluda. What you do seems good but I load to my server and it doesn't work. Perhaps I am missing something? Here I have all the code that you give, but put together: http://jsbin.com/agayih/1/edit

Comment: that's because you're using an old jquery library, you should update to jquery 1.8 or if you need 1.4 replace this line $('.send').click(function(event) {

Comment: I updated to the last jQuery library and it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/GyX77/ I get a message that says: [object][object] and I don't receive the e-mail (I put the file in my server of course) Probably is my fault, is there something I don't understand?

Comment: what doesn't work? in jsfiddle it will never work since jsfiddle doesn't have permissions to access your server. Your question was to submit the form, and the code does that using AJAX. My question is is your CGI working good? Did you understand the code? that <h1> tag or other tag/string/number you want is sent back to jquery by your server side script, php/asp/cgi, you don't need to add it to your html.

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <title>Error: Acceso denegado</title>
 </head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
<h1>Error: No tiene permiso para ejecutar este programa</h1><br><br><p><hr size=7 width=75%><p>
Por favor, consulte con su administrador web.
</body></html>

Comment: Of course I put the file in my server. I just put the code in the jsfiddle to be able to show the code as a hole.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16256/discussion-between-narcis-and-pluda)